# Heroku Postgres database plan change results in crashing application

Tags: postgresql, ssl, heroku

I just moved my data for a heroku application to a bigger database of a newer version. When restarting the application, I got an error, that has been widely discussed when connecting to databases outside of heroku.

```
app[web.1]: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "XX.XX.XX.XX", user "12345678901234", database "12345678901234", SSL off
```

The heroku [FAQ](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-logs-errors#fatal-no-pg_hba-conf-entry-for-host-user-u-database-d-ssl-off) states:

> You are attempting to establish a database connection without SSL. SSL
>   is required for connections [...] for all
>   connections on some newer databases on -0 and -2 plans. Please see the
>   documentation for your postgres driver on how to establish encrypted
>   connections.

I don't have access to the postgres options of my heroku instance, do I?
Am I missing any simple information?

Additional information: I am working with Play Framework 2.3.7 with Java. The connection is handled by Heroku with an unmutable value in an environment variable. The infrastructure is managed using Heroku Toolbelt.

Comment: Can you share a little more about 1) your platform/framework (Java Spring? Java Play? Something else?) and 2) how you are establishing the connection? While you don't have access to the PostgreSQL server's options, you can control options that your JDBC client uses. (e.g., when instantiating the connection, pass a property of "ssl" with value "true".

Comment: @bimsapi Thank you for your questions. I added the information. The question is Heroku specific and has nothing to do with manipulating a client or server as I don't have any access to them. Heroku manages everything.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have something like this in your `build.sbt`:

```
"postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4"
```

Change it to this:

```
"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4.1208"
```

This will use SSL by default as described in the [Heroku Postgresql documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#heroku-postgres-ssl).

If you cannot upgrade the library, you must manually add these parameters to the `DATABASE_URL`.

```
ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```